# how do I format a "for" loop to go through a specific yearly date range?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to execute a  python program that checks the years from 1987 to 2012, and the program must tell me how many of the years within this range have a duplicate number in them. I'm struggling to create a loop for the years 1987-2012. I have to somehow convert them from an int to a string before executing the code to count each digit.

How to have to program re-run to the next year (from 1987 to 1988 for example)?

```
#years = range(1987,2013)   
year = "1991"


cells = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for x in range(10):
      cells[x] = year.count(str(x))

print("output1=", cells)
print("\n")

for x in range(len(cells)):

    if cells[x] > 1:

        print("for ",year,x,"appears ",cells[x]," times",end=" ")
```

the results should look like
there are no duplicate digits in 1987
for 1988 8 appears 2 times
for 1989 9 appears 2 times
for 1990 9 appears 2 times

Comment: `for year in range(1987, 2013):` will give you the the loop over each year. You know there are duplicate digits if the `len(set(str(year))) != len(str(year))`, because sets do not count duplicates.

Comment: if I use range(1987, 2013) it gives me a year output that's in integer format. The second block of code starting with "cells" and downward, will work correctly but I have to manually type the year as a string at the top. Any idea how I can write a few lines of code to iterate through 1987 to 2013, and then convert them to a str?

Comment: `year = str(year)` will convert it to a string, but it looks like you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I believe that. When I put range(1987, 2013: and then str(year), it only gives me the output for year 2012. Do you know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Python is layout sensitive you have to indent all of your lower code into the loop `for year in range(1987, 2013):` so that it is run for each year. Currently it sounds like you are running the loop for year to the end and then running the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on AChampion's comment, you can iterate through the years like this:

```
start_date = 1987
end_date = 2013
counter = 0
for year in range(start_date, end_date): # Creates an iterable containing years 1987-2013
    # A set can only have unique items, so it will discard duplicates 
    # If the length of the set is less than 4, then it had to discard a duplicate
    if len(set(str(year))) != 4: 
        counter += 1
print("This date range has", counter, "years with duplicate numbers")
```